# Merge results from two tables through 1 common column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have some warehouses which we do inventory on a regular basis.

I need to make a report (the goal is to use Microsoft PowerBi) to show the discrepancies between different inventories for the same warehouse (location), but the only common column is the warehouse number.

**Product column is dynamically**: it may appear on an inventory and not on another (and that is exactly what we need to know)

Each inventory is on a different table, like this:

```
TABLE A     
LOCATION    PRODUCTS           QTY
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 1      10
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 2      100
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 333    5
WH 2        PRODUCT NO. YYY    22

TABLE B     
LOCATION    PRODUCTS            QTY
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 1       10
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 2       100
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 333     5
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. XXX     77
WH 2        PRODUCT NO. YYY     45
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. YYY     555
WH 2        PRODUCT NO. 1       14
```

Expected output should be like this:

```
Location    products           QTY A    QTY B
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 1      10       10
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 2      100      100
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. 333    5        5
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. XXX    -        77
WH 1        PRODUCT NO. YYY    -        555
WH 2        PRODUCT NO. 1      -        14
WH 2        PRODUCT NO. YYY    22       45
```

I´ve read about FULL OUTER JOIN and also PIVOT TABLES, but I was unable to fully understand and use them (and I´m also not sure they are the goal here).

SQL version is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Standard

Comment: What about the `JOIN` operator didn't you understand, perhaps we can explain that further so that you do. [SQL Joins Explained](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types)

Answer (score 2):

One option is a `Union ALL` in concert with a `PIVOT` or Conditional Aggregation

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Location
              ,Products
              ,Qty
              ,Col = 'Qty A'
         From  Table A
        Union All
        Select Location
              ,Products
              ,Qty
              ,Col = 'Qty B'
         From  Table B
       ) src
 Pivot (sum(Qty) for Col in ([Qty A],[Qty B] ) ) pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a simple full join?  Am I missing something?  Pivot seems unnecessary here.

```
select isnull(A.location,B.location) location, isnull(A.products, B.products) products,
   A.QTY A_QTY, B.QTY B_QTY
from tableA A
full outer join tableB B
   on A.location = B.location
   and A.products = B.products
```

A_QTY or B_QTY will be null if it's in one table but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with tableA (LOCATION, PRODUCTS,   QTY)
as
(
select 'WH 1','PRODUCT NO. 1',10
union all
select  'WH 1','PRODUCT NO. 2',100
union all
select  'WH 1','PRODUCT NO. 333',5
union all
select  'WH 2','PRODUCT NO. YYY',22
)
, tableB (LOCATION, PRODUCTS,   QTY)
as
(
select 'WH 1','PRODUCT NO. 1',10
union all
select 'WH 1','PRODUCT NO. 2',100
union all
select 'WH 1','PRODUCT NO. 333',5
union all
select 'WH 1','PRODUCT NO. XXX',77
union all
select 'WH 2','PRODUCT NO. YYY',45
union all
select 'WH 1','PRODUCT NO. YYY',555
union all
select 'WH 2','PRODUCT NO. 1',14
)

select
    LOCATION
,   PRODUCTS
,   isnull(QtyA,0) [Qty A]
,   isnull(QtyB,0) [Qty B]
from
(
select
    LOCATION
,   PRODUCTS
,   QTY
,   'QtyA'  ColumnQty
from    tableA
union all
select
    LOCATION
,   PRODUCTS
,   QTY
,   'QtyB'  ColumnQty
from    tableB
) source
pivot
(
sum(QTY) for ColumnQty in ([QtyA],[QtyB])
) pvt
```

I've tested it and it works as can be seen [here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=75350575fc2386466c013954f96ac9d1)